# Handling multiple 3rd party webservice calls

Tags: php, angularjs, web-services

I'm trying to build an application similar to a shopping cart but my products are populated from 3rd party API. I want to provide products from around 10 categories in a selected price range.

But the API provider have the endpoint that returns products only for 1 given category based on the stock (consider stock changes at any frequency), so I have to call the web-service 10 times and need to parse, merge & sort the results which is taking time (even `asynchronous` parallel `ajax` calls). My Tech stack is `AngularJS`, `PHP`.

Can anybody help me in improving the performance in this case.

Thanks in advance.
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Since your application needs to show product list, and i assume this list is not changing frequently. So for performance, $http AJAX caching could work. In default Angularjs configuration $http responses are not cached by default. To work with caching set config.cache value to TRUE. You can also set this to cache object created by $cacheFactory class.

Note Only GET and JSONP requests are cached.

```
$http({ cache: true, url: url, method: 'GET'}).success(...);
```

Comment: Hi Atul, but my problem is with the home page loading for the first time.